# How to export a rawEDF file to my computer

Tags: python, mne-python, european-data-format

so basically I am manipulating edf files using mne and pyedflib libraries in python. As long as I am applying many changes on my edf_file, I need to export my edf file after each modification. I tried many commands with mne and pyedflib but none of them seems to work. Does anyone have a solution please?
Any kind of help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not specify what have you tried and what you have not tried exactly I will point to the doc that it seems to fit in your case and an example directly from the lib you use.

I assume you are using the writer so here the doc for `pyedflib`:

[EDF file writer](https://pyedflib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/edfwriter.html#edf-bdf-file-writer-edfwriter)

and you should check directly this example from the pyedflib repository to adapt to your needs:

https://github.com/holgern/pyedflib/blob/master/demo/writeEDFFile.py

I think the example in the repo should give you a good idea.